Return to application from keycloak account/#personal-info page
I’m using Keycloak 22.0.5. In my app, I have an “edit profile” option that transfers the user to our themed /account#/personal-info page in keycloak to allow them to edit their name.
When the user clicks save or cancel, I want to transfer them back to my application.
2 questions:
We’ve been having trouble figuring out how to make keycloak return the user to the app, can you tell me what I we need to do?
Reality check: Are we supposed to take the user to the personal-info page? It seems useful as it allows them to self-serv their info, and to potentially configure MFA, etc, but we were suprised that there did not appear to be a straightforward way to send the user back to the app, so wanted to make sure we aren’t doing something unusual, or not supported/not recommended.

For redirecting from keycloak please refer to this document to set the parameters referrer and referrer_uri.
{KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/auth/realms/{REALM}/account?referrer={CLIENT_NAME}&referrer_uri={THE_PAGE_TO_LINK_BACK_TO}

Is this one are you looking ?
